# VBA Excel MACRO-Destination:=RANGE Active Cell instead of "Named" Range

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

Simply needing to point (RANGE) to the active cell in active worksheet. 
Destination:=Range("$A$1") needs to read "Activecell", somehow. I can't seem to get it to work. Thanks for any assistance!

```
Sub DestinationCell
   With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;\\mpls.ucare.pvt\\PB 67311 FS.csv" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))    
End sub
```

Comment: I think it should be "ActiveCell", not "Active.Cell"....

Comment: Write `Destination:= ActiveCell` in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean you want the origin cell of the QueryTable to be where ever the active cell is?

```
Sub DestinationCell()
   With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;\\mpls.ucare.pvt\\PB 67311 FS.csv" _
    , Destination:=Application.ActiveCell)
End Sub
```